# Python, jsonpath_ng: Exception: Parse error at 1:4 near token ? (?)

Tags: python, json, json-path-expression

How do I get a specific list of information from JSON through text field input?

Here is my sample JSON data (retrieved via URL). Actually, there are hundreds of items.

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "timestamp": "2020-04-03T23:24:27+08:00",
        "carpark_data": [
            {
                "carpark_info": [
                    {
                        "total_lots": "91",
                        "lot_type": "C",
                        "lots_available": "36"
                    }
                ],
                "carpark_number": "HE12",
                "update_datetime": "2020-04-03T23:23:34"
            },
            {
                "carpark_info": [
                    {
                        "total_lots": "583",
                        "lot_type": "C",
                        "lots_available": "474"
                    }
                ],
                "carpark_number": "HLM",
                "update_datetime": "2020-04-03T23:23:23"
            },
            {
                "carpark_info": [
                    {
                        "total_lots": "322",
                        "lot_type": "C",
                        "lots_available": "126"
                    }
                ],
                "carpark_number": "RHM",
                "update_datetime": "2020-04-03T23:23:35"
            },
            {
                "carpark_info": [
                    {
                        "total_lots": "97",
                        "lot_type": "C",
                        "lots_available": "85"
                    }
                ],
                "carpark_number": "BM29",
                "update_datetime": "2020-04-03T23:23:43"
            },
            {
                "carpark_info": [
                    {
                        "total_lots": "96",
                        "lot_type": "C",
                        "lots_available": "75"
                    }
                ],
                "carpark_number": "Q81",
                "update_datetime": "2020-04-03T23:23:21"
            },
            {
                "carpark_info": [
                    {
                        "total_lots": "173",
                        "lot_type": "C",
                        "lots_available": "55"
                    }
                ],
                "carpark_number": "C20",
                "update_datetime": "2020-04-03T23:23:24"
            }

        ]
    }
]}
```

I am writing the following code to get carpark_data when the user keys in a respective carpark_number in the text field, for example: `HLM`

My expected output is

```
[
  {
    "carpark_info": [
      {
        "total_lots": "583",
        "lot_type": "C",
        "lots_available": "474"
      }
    ],
    "carpark_number": "HLM",
    "update_datetime": "2020-04-03T23:23:23"
  }
]
```

I have been trying as follows, but not sure if it is possible..

```
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDInputDialog
from urllib import parse
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
from kivy.app import App
import json
from jsonpath_ng import jsonpath,parse


class SearchMenu(MDInputDialog):
   title = 'Search by Address'
   text_button_ok = 'Search'

   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
       self.size_hint = [.9, .3]
       self.events_callback = self.callback

   def callback(self,*args):
       address = self.text_field.text
       self.get()
       print(address)

   def get(self):
       url= "https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/carpark-availability"
       UrlRequest(url,on_success=self.success, on_failure=self.failure, on_error=self.error)


   def success(self,urlrequest, result):
       print("ok")
       data=[match.value for match in parse(('$..carpark_data[?(@.carpark_number =address)]')).find(result)]
       json_data=json.dumps(data, indent =2 ,separators=(',', ':'))
       print(json_data)

   def failure(self,urlrequest, result):
       print(result)
       print("failure")

   def error(self,urlrequest, result):
       print(result)
       print("error")
```

Answer (score 2):

Good question. I think you are pretty close; using this code worked for me:

```
import json
from jsonpath_ng import jsonpath
from jsonpath_ng.ext import parse
json_str = '''{"items":[{"timestamp":"2020-04-03T23:24:27+08:00","carpark_data":[{"carpark_info":[{"total_lots":"91","lot_type":"C","lots_available":"36"}],"carpark_number":"HE12","update_datetime":"2020-04-03T23:23:34"},{"carpark_info":[{"total_lots":"583","lot_type":"C","lots_available":"474"}],"carpark_number":"HLM","update_datetime":"2020-04-03T23:23:23"},{"carpark_info":[{"total_lots":"322","lot_type":"C","lots_available":"126"}],"carpark_number":"RHM","update_datetime":"2020-04-03T23:23:35"},{"carpark_info":[{"total_lots":"97","lot_type":"C","lots_available":"85"}],"carpark_number":"BM29","update_datetime":"2020-04-03T23:23:43"},{"carpark_info":[{"total_lots":"96","lot_type":"C","lots_available":"75"}],"carpark_number":"Q81","update_datetime":"2020-04-03T23:23:21"},{"carpark_info":[{"total_lots":"173","lot_type":"C","lots_available":"55"}],"carpark_number":"C20","update_datetime":"2020-04-03T23:23:24"}]}]}'''
json_obj = json.loads(json_str)
jsonpath_expr = parse('$..carpark_data[?(@.carpark_number == "HLM")]')
print([match.value for match in jsonpath_expr.find(json_obj)])
```

First, I think you have some minor syntax issues/typos in your path query

- the equal operator is actually `==` (I know, the [readme on Github](https://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng) tells otherwise! It's already [reported](https://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng/issues/60).)
- you need to wrap the search string with double quotes, i.e. in your case it shout read like this `parse('$..carpark_data[?(@.carpark_number == "'+address+'")]'`
- (also, your sample JSON was missing the closing `}` it's probably only absent in your post but not your code, right?)

Second, probably most important, you need to use a different `parse` import when using path filters `[?(..)]`:

```
from jsonpath_ng import jsonpath
from jsonpath_ng.ext import parse
```

I literally found this out by reading the [jsonpath_ng tests](https://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng/blob/master/tests/test_jsonpath_rw_ext.py) on Github and by trial and error. Fun!